# How to disable unused entry scan in Dockerfile

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Whole content of my Dockerfile is in grey because of unused entry scan in IntelliJ (2017.1.4). Is there a way to disable this only for Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 1):

Weird. Docker plugin for IDEA does not have any unused search functionality. The problem should come from some other plugin, and I can't reproduce it with the plugins bundled by default.

Please temporarily disable Docker plugin and check whether the problem remains after restart (it probably remains).
Then please temporarily disable all other plugins and check whether the problem remains after restart (it should be gone).

If you are unable to determine the problem plugin, please do the following:

- open a new youtrack (check [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack)
- set its subsystem to "Docker", with the link to this post
- attach 2 screenshots of the problem (when docker plugin *is enabled* and when it *is disabled*)
- attach IDEA log after restart

Comment: Issue created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602185/how-to-disable-unused-entry-scan-in-dockerfile